# How do I add lines to every file inside a folder?

Tags: linux

I am trying to add license declaration to all files inside a folder. Is there any shortcuts / linux commands to do that? If this can be done to files of a specific extension that will be even better.

Edit: This was my final command based on @vimsha's answer:

`find . -type f -name "*.js" -exec sh -c 'echo "/* @flow */\n$(cat $0)" > $0' {} \;`

Comment: use vim. put license into a register. then open all files in vim or use quickfix window. record a macro that insert register in top of file, do `:wn` and end macro. run macro.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

cd into the folder and execute the following command

```
find *.txt -exec sh -c 'echo "license " >> $0' {} \;
```

Above command finds all files with 'txt' extension and appends the string "license" to them. You can change it to the extension you want and the text you want to append

To add to the beginning of the file:

```
find *.txt -exec sh -c 'echo -e "license\n$(cat $0)" > $0' {} \;
```

Comment: but a license is usually at the beginning of the file, isn't it?

Comment: @vagoberto OP doesn't say where the license information needs to go. If it needs to go in the beginning, it can be done by making a small modification to the above command

Comment: @Vimsha, yeah would like to add it to the top.  Care you show us how?